# How drag and drop html inside a section

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

When we drag "Drag Header" to the page-content, we want it always go to inside <section> tag. In the example below, if you drag slowly, it may be dropped out of section tag.

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/vuktx/9nMqv/44/

This image will provide more detail: http://mangchiase.com/get/9a0fe591-71bc-4f13-861f-0f54e8277f41.image

Thank experts.

```
$('.items ul li div.widget-item').draggable({
helper: function(e) {
    //return $('<div>').addClass('block').text( $(e.target).text() );
    return $('<div>').attr("style","height: 30px;width:50px;").attr("class","entire-page-template-hover");
},
cursor: "move",
start: function() {
    $(".span12, .span6, .span4, .span3, .span2").addClass("container-border");
    //$(".drop-message").addClass("entire-page-template-hover");
},
stop: function() {
    $(".span12, .span6, .span4, .span3, .span2").removeClass("container-border");
},
connectToSortable: "#page-content"
});

$('#page-content').sortable({
helper: function(e) {
    //return $('<div>').addClass('block').text( $(e.target).text() );
    return $('<div>').attr("style","height: 30px;width:50px;").attr("class","entire-page-template-hover");
},
placeholder: 'entire-page-template-hover',
items: ".widget-item",
cursor: "move",
//containment: ".span6, .span12",
//forcePlaceholderSize: true,
start: function() {
    $(".span12, .span6, .span4, .span3, .span2").addClass("container-border");

},
stop: function() {
    $(".span12, .span6, .span4, .span3, .span2").removeClass("container-border");
},
update: function (event, ui) {
    // turn the dragged item into a "block"
    ui.item.find('.widget-icon').remove();
    ui.item.find('.hide').removeClass('hide');
    addText();
},
change: function (event, ui) {

},
receive: function (event, ui) {
    addText();

},
over: function( event, ui ) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") != 'page-content') {
        $(ui.placeholder).css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        $(ui.placeholder).css('display', '');
    }        
    //$(this).find('.drop-message').remove();
}
});
function addText () {
$('.span12, .span6, .span4, .span3, .span2').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).html('<div class="widget-item drop-message">Drop content here</div>');
    } else if ($(this).children().length > 1) {
        $(this).find('.drop-message').remove();
    }
});
}
addText();
```

Comment: div #page-content is sortable, inside it you have 2 sections. Because of this setup you can add .widget-item anywhere inside #page-content. So the sortable should be section, then .widget-items can only be added to the section.

Comment: Thank @rusln, If I change #page-content section is sortable, then placeholder didn't work. The detail of the idea is:
1. .widget-item can move between sections.
2. When we drag a widget-item, placeholder will show exactly location that we want to drop.
3. widget-item has to be inside section.

Thank,

Answer (score 0):

After take couple hours for digging, I have an solution for my own. What I gonna do is to remove the content if some cases it is put outside section tag.

Here the code that you can refer.
http://jsfiddle.net/vuktx/9nMqv/45/

The code that I mention is here.

```
$('#page-content').children().each(function() {
        if ('SECTION' != $(this).prop('tagName')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
});
```